# setNickname is not including spaces in discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

When I set someone's nickname for example Stack Overflow", It does not set It correctly. It sets my nickname to "stackoverflow", Without spaces.

My code:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
    name: 'changenickname',
    aliases: ['changenick'],
    permissions: ["MANAGE_NICKNAMES"],
    cooldown: 5,
    description: "change your target's nickname",
    usage: "d!changenickname <@user> <nickname>",
    async execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord, profileData){
        const target = message.mentions.members.first();
        const nickname = args.slice(1).join('');
        if(!target) return message.channel.send('Please specify a target to change nickname');
        if(!nickname) return message.channel.send('Please specify a nickname to change');
        if (member.roles.highest.position >= message.guild.me.roles.highest.position) return message.reply('I cannot moderate this user as their highest role is higher than mine or I have the same highest role position as them.')


        target.setNickname(nickname);
        const done = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("GREEN")
        .setTitle("✅ Done")
        .setDescription(`Changed <@${target.id}> nickname to ${nickname}`)
        .setTimestamp()
        message.channel.send({embeds: [done]})
    }
}
```

**Note:** The command sets the nickname without any error, but it must set the nicknames with spaces(if there were in args).

I am using discord.js v13 and node.js v16

[image]

Comment: Can you show your event handler as your command seems to be getting `args` from that file?

Comment: Yeah here you go: `const prefix = data.Prefix;`,`const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);`

Comment: `const nickname = args.slice(1).join('');` If `args` is an array containing firstname and lastname in indices 1 and 2, then this command will produce firstnameLastname with no spaces.

Comment: So what must I do?

Comment: Consider a different separator in your [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At line 11 you have this:

```js
const nickname = args.slice(1).join('');
```

In your case `args.slice(1)` returns the array `['The', 'God']`. The [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method takes every element of the array and puts it together in one string with the given string between every element. The string you gave to the function is `''`, so it will put the elements together without anything between it. So from the array `['The', 'God']` it makes the string `TheGod` instead of `The God`.

So what you would need is `.join(' ')`, not `.join('')`.

I hope that helps.